# Pauli exclusion principle for $H_{2}$

Tags: wavefunction, electrons, atoms, hydrogen, pauli-exclusion-principle

We know that depending on whether their spins are parallel or antiparallel, two electrons (each with spin ½) can combine to give a total spin of $1$ (parallel)or $0$ (antiparallel). But only one of these two possible values is correct for the two electrons in the ground state of a $H_{2}$ molecule.
So I'm interested in which one is correct and why; if someone can explain me, I would be very grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hydrogen molecule and its ground state are discussed in most quantum mechanics textbooks.

Comment: You can get one in a library or look in the internet. Your question really falls into the category "This question does not show research effort"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a consequence of the [Pauli Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle#Atoms) (PP), which in the case of atoms or molecules means that two electrons in the same state MUST have different spin values.

Take the simple example of a $\text{He}$ atom in the ground state $\text{1s}$ $(1, 0, 0)$. The two electrons in this state MUST have different spin, i.e. one $+\frac12$, one $-\frac12$, in order to satisfy the PP. It also means that the $\text{1s}$ orbital can only accommodate $2$ electrons, as otherwise two of them would have the same spin e.g. $\Big(+\frac12$,$-\frac12$, $-\frac12\Big)$, in violation of the PP.

It applies also to the $\text{H}_2$ molecule and the $\sigma$ molecular orbital (MO), that binds the two nuclei. One electron must have spin $+\frac12$, the other $-\frac12$. A third electron cannot be accommodated in the $\sigma$ MO, because it would automatically violate the PP.